# Finding maxium and minimum element in binary search tree

Tags: c++, search, tree, binary

I am a newbie coder . Today I learned about Binary Search Trees,saw a task of finding minimum and maximum element in bst. here is my code. i am getting the "-1" every time.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code **in the text of the question**. Don't provide links to code.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)?

Comment: Dont post code or any other text as image of it, copy paste the original text here

Comment: You never insert a `-1` into your tree, and you never return `-1` as a fail condition from your functions, so either your issue as described is wrong or the code shown is not the code you're running. Please provide the code AS TEXT.

Comment: don't use recursion when a simple loop would be sufficient...

Answer (score 2):

For a binary tree, if you always take the leftmost child, you'll find the `min` element, if you always take the rightmost child, you'll find the `max` element:

```
min_node = root;
while( min_node.left != NULL ) {
    min_node = min_node.left;
}

max_node = root;
while( max_node.right != NULL ) {
    max_node = max_node.right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both FinMin and FindMax swap the "else if" and "else" statements and you will get the right answer.